# Is it possible to measure the execution time with temporarily halt of the script with Ctrl + z?

Tags: time

I want to measure the execution time of my script, which I execute in the following way:

```
time python script.py -n 11
```

However, I also want to stop the execution of the script temporarily, especially when I'm on a cafe since the script takes all the resources of my MacBook Pro, and the battery immediately runs out. When I want to stop the execution, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>, and then issue `fg` to make the process start again.

But if I run the script with `time` command, then the `time` returns the execution time at the point of the first halt, and then all the following halt and resume are not measured.

So is it possible to measure the time with the halt command? It is great if the answer only measures the time while the script is running, and not includes the time the script is at halt.

I use MacBook Pro 15' (mid-2018) and High Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

Two options that you have available:

1) Run your command in a Bash subshell:

```
$ (time python script.py -n 11)
```

2) Use the external time command (as opposed to the built-in keyword you are using):

```
$ /usr/bin/time python script.py -n 11
```